# Laravel 5.4 saving models via async queue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue

So I am trying to optimize my site and on every page load and exit I save a metric (time on page, ip address etc) for analytics. However these are decent sized bottlenecks on my server. When viewing the time it takes for things to run my entire function takes ~1-2ms and then saving to the DB takes ~100-200ms. So my goal is to run my function and then dispatch a new job, that will do the actual saving of the metric. This way all of the saving of my models can be offloaded to a queue. Below is a copy of my job

```
class SaveMetric implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Metrics $metric)
    {
        //
        $metric->save();
    }
}
```

Then in my controller function after I grab all the values I need I run this

```
dispatch(new SaveMetric($newMetric));
```

This seems to run but does not seem to do anything. Am I missing something? (Edit) This does ~something~ it just saves a record to the DB with null in all the fields, as if I created a new metric without any values.

- Is it required to pass a queue into the job dispatch?
- Do I need to run a daemon or something similar to actually process the things in the queue?

I created the job using the artisan make:job command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty close.

```
class SaveMetric implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $metric;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param Metrics $metric
     */
    public function __construct(Metrics $metric)
    {
        $this->metric = $metric;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->metric->save();
    }
}
```

According to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues):

> In this example, note that we were able to pass an Eloquent model directly into the queued job's constructor. Because of the SerializesModels trait that the job is using, Eloquent models will be gracefully serialized and unserialized when the job is processing. If your queued job accepts an Eloquent model in its constructor, only the identifier for the model will be serialized onto the queue. When the job is actually handled, the queue system will automatically re-retrieve the full model instance from the database.

Comment: This along with removing SerializesModels trait got me my intended behaviour.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I had to remove the `SerializesModels` trait too because I want my Job to be able to save any class that inherits my `BaseModel`.